# PowerShell Custom object produced by commandlet Import-Csv

Tags: powershell-3.0

I was reading an excellent article Skipping empty CSV objects

I found this enlightening as it helped me understand some things that were
confusing me in terms of the PowerShell commandlet `Import-Csv`. I have a 
question I am hoping someone will assist me with. Please allow me to briefly provide
some background. I am sure I am missing something simple so forgive me.

Here is the contents of a small CSV file (`$csvFileToImport`) that I imported using `Import-Csv`:

```
RegionId,RegionName
6, "Northeast US"
7, "Midwest US"
8, "South US"
9, "West US"
```

I processed this using `Import-Csv`:

Command:

```
$csvFileContent = Import-Csv -Path $csvFileToImport
```

I examined the members of this object (`$csvFileContent`) and it is clear that `$csvFileContent` 
is an array of objects:

```
TypeName: System.Object[]
```

I verified that I can display the first element in this array:

Command:

```
Write-Host ("Count of `$csvFileContent = {0}" -f $csvFileContent.Count)
```

Output:

```
Count of $csvFileContent = 4
```

Listing the first item of the returned object array:

Command:

```
Write-Host ("`$csvFileContent[0] = {0}"-f $csvFileContent[0])
```

Output:

```
$csvFileContent[0] = @{RegionId=6; RegionName=Northeast US}
```

At first glance this looked to me like each array element contained a hash table but 
this is not the case by examining the object details that the first element of the array
contains:

Command:

```
$arrayElement = $csvFileContent[0]
```

Command:

```
Write-Host ("Type of object contained in the array returned from Import-Csv and the object members:")
```

Output:

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

From the article I was able to determine that the "Value" property is actually an array:

Command:

```
$whatIsThisValue = $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value
```

Output:

```
TypeName: System.Object[]
```

Again, following the example using the "Value" property I can extract the correct values
from the array:

Command:

```
Write-Host ("`$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0] = {0}, `$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[0] = {1}" -f $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0], $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[0])
```

Output:

```
$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[0] = RegionId,  $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[0] = 6
```

Command:

```
Write-Host ("`$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[1] = {0}, `$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[1] = {1}" -f $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[1], $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[1])
```

Output:

```
$csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Name[1] = RegionName, $csvFileContent[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[1] = Northeast US
```

Here is my question...

Where is it listed or notated that the array element containing the
custom object contained a property that is a "Name" array and a property
that is a "Value" array. I deduced there was a "Value" property from the article.
Is it correct for me to refer to this as a property of the custom object?
After trying some other things first (like "Key") I was able to deduce the other
property was "Name". Neither "Name" or "Value" are listed as members in the 
`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`

I am sure I am missing some piece of critical understanding and I hope someone can help me?

Thank you in advance for any advice or assistance.

Sincerely,

Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to hard. Consider the following:

```
$a = "id, region", "6, Northeast US", "7, Midwest US", "8, South US", "9, West US"
$b = ConvertTo-Csv $a
$b | Get-Member
```

This should show you that $b is a System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject, with NoteProperty 'id' and 'region'. Now you can type in

```
$b[0].region
```

and you should get back "Northeast US". You don't really want to use $b[0].PSObject.Properties.Value[0]. Just use the 'header names' from the original csv file.

You can pipe any object into Get-Member (or the alias 'gm') to find out about the properties and methods etc. Spend some time using PowerShell interactively, it is well worth it.